# Unable to find an element with testID in React Native Jest?

Tags: react-native, testing, integration-testing, ts-jest

I am new in `react-native` and creating a `react-native` mobile application. I want to implement `Integration-Testing` with help of `Jest testing library` in my app. All the required packages I have installed, but I am facing one error, that mentioned above.

Here is the my test file Auth.test.js under the **tests** folder.

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../src/App';
import 'jest-fetch-mock';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import {
  cleanup,
  render,
  waitFor,
  fireEvent,
  screen,
} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import fetchMock from 'jest-fetch-mock';

jest.useFakeTimers();

beforeEach(() => {
  fetchMock.resetMocks();
});

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
  fetchMock.resetMocks();
});

it('renders the app correctly when visiting first time', async () => {
  render(<App />);
  await waitFor(() => {});
});

it('verify the create account btn, should go to sign-up page.', async () => {
  const navigation = {navigate: () => {}};
  jest.spyOn(navigation, 'navigate');
  const appPage = render(<App />);
  await waitFor(() => {});
  const createAccountBtn = appPage.getByTestId('create_account_btn_login');
  console.log('the createAccountBtn is = ', createAccountBtn);
  fireEvent.press(createAccountBtn);
  expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('SignupScreen');
});
```

and here is the my app.tsx component

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import DashboardScreen from 'src/screens/dashboard-screens/DashboardScreen';
import LoginScreen from 'src/screens/auth-screens/LoginScreen';
import EmailVerifyScreen from 'src/screens/auth-screens/EmailVerifyScreen';
import SignupScreen from 'src/screens/auth-screens/SignupScreen';
import ConfirmSignUpScreen from 'src/screens/auth-screens/ConfirmSignUpScreen';
import ConfirmSignInScreen from 'src/screens/auth-screens/ConfirmSignInScreen';
import DynamicFormScreen from 'src/screens/dashboard-screens/DynamicFormScreen';
import DynamicCardScreen from 'src/screens/dashboard-screens/DynamicCardScreen';
import 'src/amplify_auth/amplifySetup';

import {getCurrentUser} from 'src/amplify_auth/amplifyModule';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const [isSessionCheck, setIsSessionCheck] = useState(false);
  const [sessionUser, setsessionUser] = useState<any>();
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentUser()
      .then(resut => {
        if (resut) {
          setsessionUser(resut);
          setIsSessionCheck(true);
        } else {
          setIsSessionCheck(true);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error is === ', error);
        setIsSessionCheck(true);
      });
  }, []);
  if (!isSessionCheck) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={sessionUser ? 'DashboardScreen' : 'LoginScreen'}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="LoginScreen"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SignupScreen"
          component={SignupScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ConfirmSignInScreen"
          component={ConfirmSignInScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ConfirmSignUpScreen"
          component={ConfirmSignUpScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="DashboardScreen"
          component={DashboardScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="EmailVerifyScreen"
          component={EmailVerifyScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="DynamicFormScreen" component={DynamicFormScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="DynamicCardScreen" component={DynamicCardScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this the login component where I have create account button where I have set the testID

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {Alert, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import Header from 'src/components/Header';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';
import CustomInput from 'src/components/CustomInput';
import CustomButton from 'src/components/CustomButton';
import {userSignIn} from 'src/amplify_auth/amplifyModule';

const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const {control, handleSubmit} = useForm();
  const userRef = useRef<any>();

  const onClickLogin = async data => {
    const {username, password} = data;
    try {
      const user = await userSignIn(username, password);
      console.log('Login user object is = ', user);
      userRef.current = user;
      navigation.navigate('ConfirmSignInScreen', {
        data: {
          username,
          password,
          user,
        },
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      Alert.alert(error.message);
    }
  };
  const onClickCreateAccount = () => {
    navigation.navigate('SignupScreen');
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header text="Login screen" />
      <CustomInput
        name="username"
        control={control}
        placeholder="Enter email or phone number"
        rules={{
          required: 'Username is required',
        }}
      />
      <CustomInput
        name="password"
        control={control}
        placeholder="Password"
        secureTextEntry
        rules={{
          required: 'Password is required',
          minLength: {
            value: 8,
            message: 'Password should be at least 8 characters long',
          },
        }}
      />
      <CustomButton
        testID={'login_btn_login'}
        text="Login"
        onPress={handleSubmit(onClickLogin)}
      />
      <CustomButton
        testID={'create_account_btn_login'}
        text="Create Account"
        onPress={onClickCreateAccount}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 50,
    padding: 10,
  },
});
export default LoginScreen;
```

When I try to get `const createAccountBtn = appPage.getByTestId('create_account_btn_login');`

it return nothing, what I doing wrong please advice .

here is the my test output error:-

[image]